# node not working on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu, windows-10

I am trying to make node work inside Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.

I am just starting out with using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, so I am probably doing some newbie mistake.

I have done `apt-get install` on `node`

```bash
# sudo apt-get install node
Reading package lists... Done
[...]
```

That command gives reasonable output.

But when I actually try to run the command I get no response whatsoever. No error message, nothing

```
# node -v
# node
#
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To install NodeJS in ubuntu, install `nodejs` package:

```
wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

The package `node` is not related to NodeJS.

Comment: The default `nodejs` package in the Ubuntu repo is wildly out of date for 14.04 (which is the version used in WSL) - the latest Node is v6.5.0, but [the package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nodejs) is still 0.12. Instead, follow the instructions [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) and get the latest version.

Comment: I used the command `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -` advised ont he referenced page. That worked fine too.

Comment: I really wish `node` was always the latest and up-to-date command for node and this was implemented as a standard, but its not. I had to use `nodejs` for it to work for me on windows 10 using ubuntu's bash. Thanks for the help